# MX Master 3 for Mac on Linux (ubuntu 22.04) drop connection

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

Please help me solve the problem. Connecting a mouse via bluetooth, after a few seconds the mouse stops working. I attached some logs:

**systemctl status bluetooth.service**

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-04-03 17:03:28 MSK; 12s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 46723 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76905)
     Memory: 944.0K
        CPU: 106ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─46723 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

apr 03 17:03:38 app-desktop bluetoothd[46723]: src/device.c:load_gatt_db() No cache for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
apr 03 17:03:39 app-desktop bluetoothd[46723]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
apr 03 17:03:39 app-desktop bluetoothd[46723]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
```

It seems that the mouse disables my bluetooth. After the mouse stops working, I can no longer connect any device until I reset the bluetooth. This only happens with the mouse MX Master 3 for Mac.

The same mouse, on the same bluetooth  works fine on Windows (i use USB bluetooth).

Maybe someone has ideas?

Comment: Hopefully someone has the same mouse and might be able to confirm this, but you might have good luck setting up the Logitech LogiOps app for Linux:  https://danishshakeel.me/configure-logitech-mx-master-3-on-linux-logiops/

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. This occurs when the power source is disconnected or after logging out.

```
➜  ~ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
➜  ~ journalctl -fu bluetooth.service
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.78 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
rugp. 17 22:07:18 sup bluetoothd[1068]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
```